# Что не так при импорте?

Tags: python, api

Есть код, который лежит в python-файле. К нему прикреплен импорт.

```
import technical_list

def get_all_information_exmo():
    balances = find_all_balances_in_exmo()
    exmo_list = technical_list.list_of_pairs
    for pair in exmo_list:
        symbols_pair = technical_list.find_exmo_pairs(pair[1])
        test = ExmoAPI_instance.api_query('order_book', {
        "pair": symbols_pair,
        "limit":100,
        })
        bid_price = test[f'{symbols_pair}']['bid'][0][0]
        ask_price = test[f'{symbols_pair}']['ask'][0][0]
        pair.insert(0, 'exmo')
        pair.append(float(bid_price))
        pair.append(float(ask_price))
        for balance in balances:
            if str(balance[1]) == str(pair[2]):
                pair.insert(3, float(balance[2]))
        for balance in balances:
            if str(balance[1]) == str(pair[4]):
                pair.insert(5, float(balance[2]))

    return exmo_list
```

В итоге скрепляется куча данных и на выходе мы имеем, что-то типа этого.

```
[['exmo', 'BTCUSDT', 'BTC', 0.0, 'USDT', 0.0, 47114.5, 47115.0], ['exmo', 'ETHUSDT', 'ETH', 0.0, 'USDT', 0.0, 3401.35, 3401.4], ['exmo', 'XRPUSDT', 'XRP', 0.0, 'USDT', 0.0, 1.0931, 1.0932]]
```

Если я запускаю функцию внутри этого файла, все работает без проблем.
Однако, если я создаю новый python файл, импортирую туда этот, то получаю ошибку.
Привожу пример.
Предположим, что этот файл называется exmo.py

Создаю новый. Называю его calculation.py

```
import exmo
details = exmo.get_all_information_exmo()
print(details)
```

Output

```
symbols_pair = technical_list.find_exmo_pairs(pair[0])
  File "c:\Users\Pumpetee\Desktop\work\back august 2021\Orfey_multiprotocol\technical_list.py", line 12, in find_exmo_pairs
    symbol = exmo_replace_pair_name[f'{need}']
KeyError: 'BIBYT'
```

Думаю, ладно, пойду в в technical_list. Искать 'BIBYT', которого там отродясь не было.
Содержимое:

```
exmo_replace_pair_name = { 
'BTCUSDT': 'BTC_USDT',
'ETHUSDT': 'ETH_USDT',
'XRPUSDT': 'XRP_USDT'
}
def find_exmo_pairs(pair):
    need = str(pair).upper()
    symbol = exmo_replace_pair_name[f'{need}']
    return symbol
```

Ошибок нет. В родном файле функция выполняется нормально. В новом почему-то тупит.
Что делаю неправильно?

UPD. Перенес полностью всю конструкцию из technical.py в exmo.py
Начала ругаться на тоже самое, что и в импорте. Но уже внутри файла.
Видимо, нельзя применять литерал в этой конструкции.

Comment: Плохо, что у вас эта функция не получает явно данные на вход, а пользуется какими-то другими функциями для получения данных. Эти функции импортируются из того же файла или где они вообще? Вы проверяли, что эти функции возвращают?

Comment: Да, конечно. Просто у них этой биржи дибильный синтаксис. У всех параметр подается просто BTCUSDT. 99% делают так. А у этих BTC_USDT.  Из-за пришлось написать обработчик, который через таблицу распознает и конвертирует с нижним подчеркиванием. Автоматизировать процесс нельзя, ибо валют около 320 и постоянно новые появляются. Самому иногда не понятно, где это символ ставить надо.

Comment: Да. Есть три файла. techinal_list.py импортируется в exmo.py для того, чтобы найти необходимую пару. Далее уже exmo.py импортируется в calculation.py

Answer (score 0):

При импорте литералы не работают. Не знаю, почему.
Проблему решил, заменив конструкцию с литералом.

```
def find_exmo_pairs(pair):
    need = str(pair).upper()
    symbol = exmo_replace_pair_name[f'{need}']
    return symbol
```

заменил на

```
def find_exmo_pairs(pair):# Поиск замены для стандартных арбитражей EXMO
    need = str(pair).upper()
    for s in exmo_replace_pair_name.items():
        if str(s[0]) == str(need):
            symbol = str(s[1])
            print(symbol)
            return symbol
```